# How to configure remote EJB connection details in wildfly-config.xml for a EJB client application deployed on JBoss EAP 7.1?

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.1, wildfly-10, jboss-eap-7

How to configure remote EJB connection details in wildfly-config.xml for a EJB client application deployed on JBoss EAP 7.1?

I tried placing it inside /META-INF folder of the EJB Jar and configure below tags but it doesn't seems to work pick the configuration from there.

```
<configuration>

<jboss-ejb-client xmlns="urn:jboss:wildfly-client-ejb:3.0">
    <invocation-timeout seconds="10"/>
    <connections>
        <connection uri="remote+http://x.y.d.c:8080"/>
    </connections>
</jboss-ejb-client>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"wildfly-config.xml" was introduced in EAP 7.1 as a common configuration file for all client configuration files. For EJB it would replace "jboss-ejb-client.properties" file which is configured for EJB standalone client applications.

So ideally I think "wildfly-config.xml" would only work on standalone EJB application, not with the application deployed to JBoss server.

For EJB client deployed on EAP, there is an alternative to configure ejb-receivers "jboss-ejb-client.xml" File and place it in /META-INF folder.

Eg -:

```
<ejb-receivers>
  <!-- This is the connection to access the application. -->
  <remoting-ejb-receiver outbound-connection-ref="remote-ejb-connection-1" />
</ejb-receivers>
```

Please try the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...let me try it.